# Double columns in SQL query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to output my SQL query directly into a table (without assigning the results to variables). Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM sites';
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '<table>';

$count = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<tr>';
    $count = $count + 1;
    if($count == 1) {                //Header row
        foreach($row as $name => $value) {
            echo '<th>' . $name . '</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr/><tr>';
    }

    foreach($row as $name => $value) {   //Data rows
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

However, in the results I get double columns, like this:

```
0 | ID | 1 | URL | 2 | startDate | etc
1 | 1  | a | a   | b | b         | etc
```

Here are a couple sample rows:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [ID] => 1 [1] => dadf [URL] => dadf
        [2] => asdf [startDate] => asdf [3] => [server] =>
        [4] => asdf [paymentStatus] => asdf
        [5] => [hostingType] => [6] => [hostingPlan] => ) 

Array ( [0] => 2 [ID] => 2 [1] => hihi [URL] => hihi.com
        [2] => [startDate] => [3] => [server] =>
        [4] => [paymentStatus] => [5] => [hostingType] =>
        [6] => [hostingPlan] => )
```

I have no idea where these numbered duplicate columns are coming from. They are not present in the database, of course, but they are in the result rows. Maybe there is a completely different way of doing what I am attempting to do?

Comment: This seems to be `PHP`. Correct?

Comment: try `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

The part about it being deprecated is interesting, but you'll probably want to look at the `result_type` parameter and pass `MYSQL_ASSOC`

There's an equivalent (also deprecated) function to do this in one call:

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Thanks Laurence. That fixed it. I suppose there is a non-deprecated way to deal with this too.